# Who is $R_\alpha(1) - \alpha$, where $R_\alpha$ is the rotation on the unit circle?

Tags: number-theory, rotations

Let $S^1 = \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ and for $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q}$ define the rotation 
$$R_\alpha(x) = x + \alpha \mod 1.$$
I don't understand who is
$$R_\alpha(1) - \alpha.$$
Is $R_\alpha(1) - \alpha = (1 + \alpha \mod 1) - \alpha = \{1 + \alpha\} - \alpha$, where $(1 + \alpha \mod 1) = \{1 + \alpha\}$  is the fractional part of $1 + \alpha$?

P.S. Can someone explain me who is $R_\alpha(x) - \alpha$ in general?

Comment: $\{ {\alpha  + 1}\} = { \alpha}$ and ${\{  \alpha} \}  - \alpha \in \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: So, who is $R_\alpha(1) - \alpha$? Thank you!

Comment: All integers are identified as one because of $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$. so $R_{\alpha}(1)- \alpha $ is in the class [1].

Comment: If we define the function $f(x) := R_\alpha(x) - \alpha$, how can I compute $f(R_\alpha(1) - \alpha)$? Thank you!

Comment: First see, how the elements of $\mathbb{R}/ \mathbb{Z}$ look like... they are the equivalence classes so f(1) will go to equivalence class of 1.

Comment: $[1] = \{1 + m : m \in \mathbb{Z}\}$. So there is $m \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $R_\alpha(1) - \alpha = 1 + m$. Then $f(R_\alpha(1) - \alpha) = f(1 + m) = R_\alpha(1 + m) - \alpha = \{1 + m + \alpha \} - \alpha = \{\alpha\} - \alpha = R_\alpha(1) - \alpha$. Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is in the definitions. First, a point on the circle $S^1$ is parametrized by an angle $x\in \mathbf R$, but this parametrization is not a bijection, $x$ being defined only up to an *integer* multiple of say $2\pi$. So that  actually $S^1\cong \mathbf R/2\pi \mathbf Z\cong \mathbf R/\mathbf Z$ as additive groups; this is indeed the correct mathematical definition of angles and their addition law, the last isomorphism amounting to the choice of a unity of measurement). Second, how to define what you call the group, say $Rot$, of rotations $R_\alpha$ ? If we do not put any restriction on  $\alpha$, the previous definition of angles would imply $Rot\cong S^1$. So your written isomorphism $Rot\cong \mathbf Q/\mathbf Z$ means that you actually consider only rotations whose angles are *rational*  multiples of $2\pi$.

This being settled, let us slightly abuse language by writing also $x$ and $\alpha$ for representatives of resp. $x\in S^1$ and $\alpha \in  Rot$. Then, by the addition law defined above, $R_\alpha (x)\in S^1$  is represented by the angle $x+\alpha+2k\pi$, and $R_\alpha (x)-x$ by $2k\pi$. Geometrically, if you choose (necessarily in an arbitrary way) a system of coordinates in the plane, the point $R_\alpha (x)-x$ could be viewed as the intersection $A$ of the circle and the abscissa axis. What about  $R_\alpha (1)$ ? Your notation $1\in S^1$, given our previous definitions, should mean the point of the circle defined by the angle = say $1$ radian. But I guess that there could be a confusion in your mind with the intersection point $A$ just introduced.